# Loop through a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have following code using class and dictionary that takes state and capital, but I'm unable to retrieve the values by looping through. Need assistance is clearing up the error that occurs in `foreach` loop.

```
public class State {
  public string Capital { get; set; }
  public int Population { get; set; }
  public int Size { get; set; }

  public State(string aCapital, int aPopulation, int aSize) {
    Capital = aCapital;
    Population = aPopulation;
    Size = aSize;
  } // Constructor of the class State

  public static Dictionary<string, State> GetStates() {
    Dictionary<string, State> myStates = new Dictionary<string, State>(); // need the () because its a class

    // myStates takes 2 values, one is a string , that is a state and State ,  which is inturn takes 3 values - 
    // Capital,Population, size

    State addStateCapital = new State("Montgomery", 214141, 244);
    myStates.Add("Alabama", addStateCapital);
    // second set
    addStateCapital = new State("Sacramento", 214141, 244);
    myStates.Add("California", addStateCapital);

    return myStates;
  }
}
```

and my Main program is as follows.. But I get error..

```
 var theState= State.GetStates();

 // this prints one item in a dictionary

 Console.WriteLine("State Capital of California is " +   theState["California"].Capital);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string,object> entry in theState)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + " State Capital  is " +  entry.Value.ToString());
}
```

ERROR on `foreach`:

> `Cannot convert keyvaluePair   <string,DictionaryDemo.State> to System... Generic KVP<string,object>`

Need help in understanding how to correctly retrieve the values.

Comment: It's telling you the error in the error message; you're trying to convert a `KeyValuePair<string, State>` to a `KeyValuePair<string, object>`. I suggest just using `foreach (var entry in theState)`.

Answer (score 2):

1) Use State instead of Object in KeyValuePair<,>.
Since you have already specified specified in State.GetStates() return type has

```
 Dictionary<string, State>
```

2) Also change the entry.Value.ToString() to **entry.Value.Capital**. Since it will not show the State Name but the Class Object Name. Therefore, change it **entry.Value.Capital**

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,State> entry in theState)
 {
 Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + " State Capital  is " +  entry.Value.Capital);
 }
```

Comment: @VajraAyudha let me know how this goes for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `GetStates()` method returns `Dictionary<string, State>`, so in this line

```
var theState= State.GetStates();
```

the variable `theState` is assigned to type `Dictionary<string, State>`. But in the following *foreach* block you try to access the values of the dictionary as `KeyValuePair<string, object>`.

So you have to use it like this:

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, State> entry in theState)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + " State Capital  is " +  entry.Value.Capital);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code snippet to below will solve your problem

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, State> entry in theState)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + " State Capital  is " +  entry.Value.Capital);
 }
```

But to understand why you were getting that error, you may want to take a closer look of definition of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` which is derived from `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. So when you use foreach loop, internally it acts on  `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. Here compiler expects each entity in foreach to be of type `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. Now since in dictionary you have `TValue` is of type State that why compiler expects `KeyValuePair<string, State>`. Now to get in-depth understanding on this, you may want to go through "covariant and contravariant concepts c#"